# trying to get image from directory using php

Tags: php, image, opencart

Opencart Ver 1.5.5.1
trying to have custom image instead of site logo.

```
$template->data['logo'] = $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

So code is currently looking at the image that is set as the logo from the backend(the database). How do I get it so it looks at an image from one of my sites folders instead?

I can then still use 'logo' as the variable which is being used in a .tpl file like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just specify the image directory and the image name:

```
$template->data['logo'] = "/path/to/image.png";
```

or if the image is on a different server:

```
$template->data['logo'] = "http://example.com/path/to/image.png";
```